# How can I regroup Array of objects by given field

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I have given array of objects, something like this

```js
const data = [
    {id: 1,  name: 'Alex', job: 'IT'},
    {id: 2,  name: 'Pavel', job: 'IT'},
    {id: 3,  name: 'Joe', job: 'IT'},
    {id: 4,  name: 'Josh', job: 'IT'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Max', job: 'teacher'},
    {id: 6, name: 'Sam', job: 'teacher'}
]
```

I need array of arrays filtered by field job

```js
const result = [
    {job: 'IT', 
    workersInfo: [
    {id:1, name:'Alex'}, 
    {id:2, name:'Pavel'}, 
    {id:3, name:'Joe'}, 
    {id:4, name:'Josh'}
    ]
    }, 
    {job: 'teacher', 
    workersInfo: [
    {id:5, name: 'Max'}, 
    {id:6, name: 'Sam'}
    ]  
    }
]
```

I tried this, but It's not what I want

```js
const data = [
    {id: 1,  name: 'Alex', job: 'IT'},
    {id: 2,  name: 'Pavel', job: 'IT'},
    {id: 3,  name: 'Joe', job: 'IT'},
    {id: 4,  name: 'Josh', job: 'IT'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Max', job: 'teacher'},
    {id: 6, name: 'Sam', job: 'teacher'}
]

const groupList = data.reduce((reduce, it) => { 
        reduce[it.job] = reduce[it.job] || [];
        reduce[it.job].push({id: it.id, name: it.name});
        return reduce;
 }, {})


console.log(Object.values(groupList));
```

How can I add new key workers Info and push info to this field

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this? All the information exists in an easy to filter state in your original data. This seems like an additional and unnecessary complication.

Comment: I am trying to render this data depending on person's job. I get this data from database. I want to create a table with 3 columns (or more). That's why I want to edit data

Comment: Just saw your message. @muratkkk, why do you need to edit the data in this form, I guess you want to list the data in the table? You should just use ```filter()``` to get the data by job, such as ```data.filter(x=>x.job === "IT")```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new object on each iteration instead of an array you can then use `Object.values`:

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1,  name: 'Alex', job: 'IT'},
  {id: 2,  name: 'Pavel', job: 'IT'},
  {id: 3,  name: 'Joe', job: 'IT'},
  {id: 4,  name: 'Josh', job: 'IT'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Max', job: 'teacher'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Sam', job: 'teacher'}
];

const groupList = data.reduce((acc, { job, id, name }) => {
  acc[job] = acc[job] || { job, workersInfo: [] };
  acc[job].workersInfo.push({ id, name });
  return acc;
}, {})


console.log(Object.values(groupList));
```

Comment: @muratkkk, I thought this solution is the fastest at first, but when I check the bench mark, mine is actually fater....

Comment: @ikhvjs This solution is a lot easier to understand

Comment: @nickzoum, I see. fewer codes indeed. It should be a frontend job, I guess performance is not an issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Example below**

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Alex", job: "IT" },
  { id: 2, name: "Pavel", job: "IT" },
  { id: 3, name: "Joe", job: "IT" },
  { id: 4, name: "Josh", job: "IT" },
  { id: 5, name: "Max", job: "teacher" },
  { id: 6, name: "Sam", job: "teacher" },
];

const output = data.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(a => a.job === o.job);
  if (index !== -1) {
    acc[index].workersInfo.push({ id: o.id, name: o.name });
  } else {
    acc.push({
      job: o.job,
      workersInfo: [{ id: o.id, name: o.name }],
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank, that's great solution

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work ?

````
const groupBy = function(xs, key) {
     return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
     (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
     return rv;
  }, {});
};

console.log(groupBy(['one', 'two', 'three'], 'length'));

// => {3: ["one", "two"], 5: ["three"]}```
````

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient and comprehensible if instead of having a structure like `Array<{job: string, workForce: Array}>`, you had something like `{[job: string]: Array}`

```js
var data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alex', job: 'IT' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Pavel', job: 'IT' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Joe', job: 'IT' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Josh', job: 'IT' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Max', job: 'teacher' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Sam', job: 'teacher' }
];

var jobs = data.reduce(function (result, person) {
    var jobList = result[person.job];
    if (!jobList) {
        jobList = [];
        result[person.job] = jobList;
    }
    jobList.push(person);
    return result;
}, {});

console.log(jobs);
```